# Ik moving a leg in the wrong direction

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

i am trying to rig a leg, but while it works ok-ish when moving forward, it bends in a way that it is not supposed to backwards[image]

[image]

In both times i tried using shift+X to not move in the x axis, but the armature rotates by itself to the side of the mesh.
Here is the blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/86942948dc44427882bfe4092317a440

Comment: Set IK limits in the bone properties tab for each bone in the leg. For example, the lower leg bone should have two of three axes locked, and the last one limited to rotating only 0-170 degrees or so, thus constituting a knee joint.

Comment: I tried it, and it is still not working.

Comment: what is happening? Did it not respond at all?

Comment: I guess the IK just try to follow the Pole Target bone called Guia joelho, so if you don't want the IK to pivot, just keep Guia joelho in front of the leg and keyframe, or deparent from the controller bone so that it doesn't follow

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard it did respond, but only when i locked all axes, so it became basically a single bone, which was not what i needed exactly.

Comment: @moonboots well, this did help a bit, but it is still not perfect, when i move it backward it still goes to the side, just a little less, and i am not sure what did you meant with the keyframe, isn't that something you use to animate?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's any problem with your leg, maybe bend the knee a bit forwards in *Edit* mode though. What happens is that, as **your pole target bone is parented to the controller**, when you move your controller it also moves the pole target bone and if you move it backward at one point it makes the knee rotate, as **the IK bone is supposed to point towards the pole target**. If you don't want that you can either deparent the pole target (you don't have to parent it to the controller) or, when you create your animation, keyframe it so that it is always at a position that doesn't cause this flipped knee effect.